# chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError for HTTP connection

Tags: javascript, sockets, http, tcp, google-chrome-app

I am listening for HTTP requests to localhost on a specified port using `chrome.sockets.tcpServer` running in a Chrome App. I'm basing my app on  the code samples from Google:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network#tcpServer.

The HTTP requests are coming from a single instance of a Flash application. It starts off working okay. When the first request comes through, the Chrome app makes a connection with a client socket, and seems to use this connection for subsequent requests.

Sooner or later though in the same session, Chrome will open another client socket for a given request, then will quickly throw a `chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError` for the new client socket. Then the original socket will also throw the same error, and no sockets remain connected.

The Flash code is just making a regular HTTP request (it's not specifically asking for a new port).

Does anyone know:

- what do I need to do to keep all requests on the same client socket id?
- or how do I get the server to cope with changing sockets?

I've put the server code here if anyone has time to take a look:

https://github.com/tarling/http-test/tree/flash/js

I wondered if it was something to do with "Connection: keep-alive" so have included this in the HTTP response header

https://github.com/tarling/http-test/blob/flash/js/http.js#L52

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed it. Updated code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/tarling/http-test/tree/flash/js)

Changes were:

- recognising a result code of -100 from `chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError` as a disconnection, and so disconnecting and closing the client socket. This was after looking at [this code](https://github.com/MenfiosINC/IRCFRHB2/blob/7c24576c702fda65c9c24e97458c15d369f406a2/package/bin/net/ssl_socket.js)
- remembering the lclient socket ID from the last successful `chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError` call for subsequent sends
- only needing to register listeners for the onReceive and onReceiveError events once.